# Why iPad and iPhone reject socket connection?

Tags: java, ipad, sockets, network-programming

I have developed Spring based web application to see videos. It's working good via desktop. But if i try to open my application from iPad and iPhone i can't play video. Because jwplayer can't get data from server. jwplayer display the error like **"The video could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed, or because the format is not supported"**, Same time server side error is

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:170)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.flush(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:221)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpGenerator.flush(HttpGenerator.java:725)
```

I have searched net and findout the reason. **Client(iPad/iPhone) terminate server connection.** That's Broken Pipe Exception. Please refer my server side code also

```
private void sendFile(HttpServletResponse response, String filename, String directory, String contentType, String extention) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    final String file = directory + File.separator + filename + "." + extention;

    response.setContentLength((int) new File(file).length());
    response.setContentType(contentType);     
    try {
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
         ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();        
            IOUtils.copyLarge(inputStream, outputStream);
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(outputStream);
    } catch (Exception exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
}
```

Broken Pipe occurred while copying inputStream to outputStream, IOUtils.copyLarge(inputStream, outputStream).

How can i solve this problem. Anyone please guide me in proper way..

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1):

Solve which problem? The solution to the unsupported video problem is to send a supported video type, and the solution to the broken pipe exception is to solve the unsupported video problem.